# Slim PHP - Right way to use request and response objects

Tags: php, slim

I'm new to Slim and PHP, but I'm trying to do a simple rest API with Slim. It's working, but I don't know if I'm doing it the right way and I cannot find another way to do it.

For example, I've a route like that:

```
$app->get('/contacts', '\Namespace\Class:method');
```

The method:

```
    public function searchContacts($request, $response) {

         return Contact::searchContacts($resquest, $response);
    }
```

So, the unique way I found to access request and response from other classes is by passing the objects as params. Is it correct or is there a better (right) way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your way is not good.

Controller should process request and return response.
Your model(`Contact`) should'nt process requests. It should take needed params and return data.

Simple example:

```
public function searchContacts($request, $response) 
{
    // to example, you pass only name of contact
    $results = Contact::searchContacts($request->get('contactName'));
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($results));

    return $response;
}
```

You don't need access to `Request` and `Response` objects from another classes. If it required, possible your architecture is wrong.

Good example from official site: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html#create-routes

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to get the values from params and recieved the response in method.

```
$app->get('/contacts', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
     $Contactname = $request->getAttribute('contact');
//You can put your search code here.
     $response->getBody()->write("Contact name is, $name");

     return $response;
});
```